# How to position wpftoolkit column chart legend at the bottom?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

The wpftoolkit column chart positions the legend automatically on the right side of the chart. I would like to get to know how I can position the legend at the bottom?

**XAML**:

```
<DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="colChart" Width="380" Height="250" Background="Azure">
    <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <DVC:ColumnSeries Title="Daily Sales" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
        </DVC:ColumnSeries>
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
</DVC:Chart>
```

**CS**:

```
public Analysis()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadColumnChartData();
}

private void LoadColumnChartData()
{
    ((ColumnSeries)colChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =

    new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Col3", 240),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Col2", 170),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Col1", 120) };  
}
```

Comment: By cganhing its ControlTemplate somehow, though it requires some work.

Comment: And for this work that has to take place I am asking for.